# Running Apache 2.2 as another user on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, permissions

I would like to run apache as a limited user on Windows 2008 R2 for security reasons. I've created a user in the user group (let's call it apache), and set the user to run as in the services pane, but then I am unable to start the service (probably not enough permission to bind to port 80). What is the minimum privileges needed to run apache on windows 2008, or what should I do to allow the user apache to bind apache 2.2 to port 80?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure Windows has the same restrictions as Linux on creating service ports under the 1024 mark.  Did you make sure you granted the user the rights to logon as a service?  This is more than just changing the service to run as that user. Click start, and in the search box, type "gpedit.msc" and hit enter.  When it's opened, go to the following path:

```
\Computer Configuration
  \Windows Settings
    \Security Settings
      \Local Policies
        \User Rights Assignment
```

Look for the option "Log on as a service", and double click.  If the new user is not in there, click "Add user or group", and add it.  Try restarting the service again.

If it still fails, try looking in the windows even log, specifically the system, and application logs, and see if there are any errors.